# PCM CCM Converter using SIMetrix/SIMPLIS

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, buck

I have built the attached file which is a peak current mode buck converter on SIMetrix/SIMPLIS software but I cannot simulate due to some errors that I could not troubleshoot. Please can anyone resolve the problem to me?
[image]

Here is the link to download my file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=14U9AxbnpqrWlDvse91k5KQVtTGo5skSz

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @winny : the message is "The periodic operating point (POP) analysis
has failed to converge.  AC analysis will
not be performed.
". I checked all the frequencies and nodes but I could not figure out where is the problem

Comment: do you need POP? or is AC analysis good enpugh?

Comment: AC analysis works with POP

Comment: I've troubleshooted the simulation errors. It is in the maximum period set to POP trigger. I have adjusted the period and the simulation worked. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Hi I'm having trouble with POP Trigger placement and setup.
Could you please tell me which part of your schematic you have modified?